# Nuitka failing to compile in python 3.11 due to exceptiongroup

Tags: python, nuitka

I tried compiling python code using nuitka and python 3.11, but I am facing this error that states that an exception occurred when compiling exception group.

```
module.exceptiongroup._catch.c: In function 'impl_exceptiongroup$_catch$$$function__4_handle_exception':
module.exceptiongroup._catch.c:633:45: error: 'PyBaseexceptiongroup_Type' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'PyBaseExceptionGroupObject'?
  633 |         tmp_isinstance_cls_1 = (PyObject *)&PyBaseexceptiongroup_Type;
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             PyBaseExceptionGroupObject
module.exceptiongroup._catch.c: In function 'impl_exceptiongroup$_catch$$$function__5_catch':
module.exceptiongroup._catch.c:2883:49: error: 'PyBaseexceptiongroup_Type' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'PyBaseExceptionGroupObject'?
 2883 |         tmp_issubclass_classes_3 = (PyObject *)&PyBaseexceptiongroup_Type;
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                 PyBaseExceptionGroupObject
```

What could be at fault here? Tried both the main and development branches of the nuitka project with the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
See https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/2355

Original answer:
Did your code work with other versions of python?

Assuming you mentioned the python version just to provide details on your environment, my first guess is that the failure is a bug in code that is normally unused. Unused code won't throw an error when running it in python, but Nuitka will throw an error.

Comment: I did not test other versions of python, since I am using 3.11 features. What do you mean by unused code?

Comment: By unused code I mean a function that never gets called, or an if/else clause that never gets executed or other code that never gets run by python, but exists in a .py file included in your code.